# Allow remote connection to windows 8 postgresql from linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, python, postgresql

I followed the instructions on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database).

My `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\postgresql.conf` reads:

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

and my `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\pg_hba.conf` reads:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Yet, when I run the following:

```
conn_string = 'postgresql://user:pass@my.ip/postgres'
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
import traceback
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine(conn_string, echo=True)
engine.connect()
```

I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "my.ip" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But I already created an inbound rule on port 5432 of my pc:
[image]

The username and password were copied directly from a pre-existing script using `localhost` which works perfectly.

I have fully rebooted the PC since making these changes.

Does anyone have any input on something that I may have missed?

I believe I made the correct modifications to my firewall:
Firewall image 1
[image]
Firewall image 2
[image]

Netstat image
[image]

Comment: windows machine is your local machine? check firewall

Comment: I have enabled the firewall I can update the q later to show

Comment: @amitsingh I posted the images that I feel show my correct firewall edits

Comment: Are you sure postgres is started and listening? try: netstat -na | find "5432"

Comment: @HoD I updated my question to show the result of the netstat command

Comment: Disable the firewall entirely for testing. If it does not work after this you can rule out the firewall and look elsewhere for the problem. If it works you know the firewall is the problem.

Comment: @duenni yes i have tried disabling the firewall completely and attempted to connect remotely.it did not work

Comment: What is behind `my.ip` ? an IPv4 address? IPv6? An entry in /etc/hosts ? An entry in the DNS? The firewall rule seems to be for IPv6 and postgres listens on both but the pg_hba.conf is for IPv4, and besides is wrong: `0.0.0.0/32` can't match, you probably meant `0.0.0.0/0` even if that's not the cause of the error message.